# NO bit stream picker in video js for dash

Tags: video.js, mpeg-dash, mpd

i am trying to run dashed files in video.js which runs smooth with my code i was wondering if there is any way to extract bit-streams and show them on control bar of player.so that a user could switch between bit rates?
thanks

```
<body>
    <video id="example-video" width="1000" height="600" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls></video>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var player = videojs('example-video');

player.ready(function() {
  player.src({
    src: 'http://127.0.0.1/demo/150219236637491.mpd',
    type: 'application/dash+xml'
  });

  player.play();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin which allows you do this:

https://github.com/streamroot/videojs-quality-picker

Comment: Hi Mick thanks for your recommendation 
i already have seen this link and checked its example its not supporting files with `.mpd` extension the file should be with `.m3u8` i want something that supports `.mpd` files.
also in example there is no quality picker button it just automatically changes quality which mpd files are handling already.

Comment: Well, they intend it to be able to be built into any project - the example one they have built it into is their HLS extension. There are other choices if you prefer, such as: https://github.com/MetaCDN/videojs-shaka-player (which has Shaka player dependency also).

Comment: Thanks mate you are a life saver this one worked so smoothly thank you soo much :)

Comment: i have seen this link before but i was too lazy to test it out but credit goes to you.